# How to call a Usercontrol from another in same window in WPF ?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have two UserControls in my project's MainWindow. In `MainWindow` I call the first  UserControl whose content is a `Button` and put this FirstControl in a Grid. How can I call the second UserControl when I click on the button in `FirstUserControl` in MainWindow?
**First UserControl :**

```
<UserControl x:Class="BenashManage.UserControl.ButtonUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             Height="auto" Width="auto" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="BorderAddEdit"  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="5,5,5,5" CornerRadius="9,9,9,9" Background="{x:Null}">
            <Grid Margin="0.2,0.2,5.4,4.2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Content="one"  TextBlock.Foreground="White"  Grid.Row="1"  Margin="9,9,9,9"                  Height="28" TextBlock.FontSize="15" Name="btn_MartyMang" Click="click_Marty"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Second UserControl:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="BenashManage.UserControl.InjuredUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             Height="auto" Width="auto"
             mc:Ignorable="d" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14"   TextBlock.Foreground="White">

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="auto" Width="360"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Border x:Name="BorderAddEdit"  Margin="6,2,6,6"  BorderThickness="5,5,5,5" CornerRadius="9,9,9,9" Background="{x:Null}">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20.8"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=":jjj" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,4,-0.4,3"/>
                <TextBox  Grid.Row="6" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,2.8,2.2,2.2" />

            </Grid>
        </Border>

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow:**

```
<Window x:Class="BenashManage.MartyrManage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:BenashManage.UserControl"
        Title="MartyrManage" Height="550" Width="550"  Style="{DynamicResource ModalWindowStyle}" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Close"
        Executed="CloseCommand_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid >
        <Grid Margin="179,10,10.4,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
*******
Height="456" Width="357" Name="MoveToUserControl" ></Grid>
        <Grid Margin="10,71,372.4,67" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="338" Width="auto" Name="ButtonManage" >
            <controls:FirstUserControl Margin="0,0,0,92">

            </controls:FirstUserControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You can create an instance of your second UserControl and add it as child of Grid or whatever container you use.

Comment: I want both usercontrol in mainwindow but first usercontrol call secund usercontrol when click button. when I show mainwindow I don't show secundusercontrol

Comment: You can implement an attached property on the second user control that can be bound to an attached property on the first control

Comment: Can you show me, how do that!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

1) Get the parent of the UserControl and then get its children.

```
(((control1).Parent as Panel).Children[1] as UserControl)
```

2) Raise an event in the one UserControl which is handled by MainWindow to call the function in the other UserControl.

Comment: In my code, I call second  UserControl from first UserControl when click button by this code :  firstUserControl add = new firstControl();
            //grid.Children.Clear();
            //grid.Children.Add(add); but I can't access from first usercontrol to grid view in MainWindow

Comment: You shouldn't clear the grid. Instead, set Visibility of the first UserControl to Collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:
in FirstUserControl event Button_Click:

```
var b = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
b.SecondUserControl.DoWhatYouNeed...;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).